# layout file path from viewstart.cshtml is being appended to view path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Look at the paths in this error:

> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The layout page 
>   "~Areas/SongTracker/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml" could not be found at the following path: 
>   "~/Areas/SongTracker/Views/Home/~Areas/SongTracker/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml".

This is the _viewstart.cshtml file in the View -> Home directory

```
@{ 
Layout = "~Areas/SongTracker/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Why is it appending the layout file path to the view directory path?  Note that the view directory is in an area in a MVC4 project.

This is my register routes function from global.asax.cs (default stuff here):

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  I was missing the / after the ~ like this:

```
"~/Areas/SongTracker/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml"
```